# Wordpress Toolkit (Plesk) detects two sites on my domain when there is only one (+ strange ghosting effect...)

Tags: wordpress, plesk, toolkit

**Context**

Hi, I recently created a new wordpress site for one of my clients. I first created it in a subdomain of the target domain. before dragging it to the target directory via FTP. Once finished, I moved the content of the old site file (a prestashop) from the root (httpdocs) to another file on the server, then I finally dragged the new wordpress site before on this same root (httpdocs). All this was done via FTP. All this was done via FTP, but I had to restart the moves several times.

**Problem**

Wordpress Toolkit now detects two Wordpress sites (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpi1t.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03kQl.png)) on the main domain and I observe some really strange behaviors, for example :

- When I delete one of the two sites via the Toolkit, it then automatically returns to the list
- Both sites have exactly the same data (status, plug-ins, databases, ...) in the Toolkit
- Some changes made on Wordpress actually appear on the page in question, but when reloading, they go away, then come back, as if there were actually two sites that overlapped: one that is affected by the changes and the other that remains unchanged and that are randomly chosen to be displayed on my browser.
- Another finding that supports this is that when I log out of the WordPress admin console, and then return to the site as a visitor, the admin banner is still there at the top of the page, proving that I am still logged in

So I don't know if it's a problem with the configuration of WordPress files like .htaccess/wp-config or if other files were corrupted by the FTP moves or even both cases. It seems to me that there is only one Wordpress in my httpdocs and I don't really know where to look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all the files from the server, having first uploaded the folder containing my wordpress via FTP. I then recreated httpdocs again then uploaded the site, some files were no longer present and created some 404, I added them by hand based on an old version of the site that I had in backup.